# how to implement custom key in mobile app with sfmc cordova plugin

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, cordova

mobile app uses MC Cordova plug in to receive push notification. Push messages are published from Marketing Cloud and we are trying to use custom keys to add metadata in the payload. The custom keys are enabled and mapped in Marketing Cloud. But in MC doc, https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_mp_custom_keys.htm&type=5, it states "mobile app developer must implement custom keys before you can use them". Would someone have reference on what/where mobile app developer need to implement?

Answer (score 3):

Please see the SDK documentation https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/push-notifications/custom-keys.html

What you need is literally in the "see also" on the page you referenced in your question.
[image]

Comment: thanks for the response Bill. i went thru that post already, it's only showing how to extract the value, but it's not clear to me where to "implement". Say, I defined custom key "testParam1" in Marketing Cloud app admin config, where does the mobile app developer need to "implement" so when we can extract this key's value from "userInfo"?

Comment: The sentence currently directly above the code snippets on that documentation page states, "To implement custom key support in your application, extend your push notification handler to extract the push’s userInfo dictionary and the values contained in it."

Comment: See #4 on the Cordova documentation page (ref. https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MC-Cordova-Plugin#4-enable-ios-push)